# How to use jsp files of another project in eclipse

Tags: java, jsp

I am developing a web application using spring and hibernate in multiple modules.

And i want to use a module which is another project into different project.
But i am unable to use jsp files of that module.

Actually i have 2 projects named profile and SecondProject. And i have a jsp file named Insert.jsp in profile project. And Insert2.jsp file in SecondProject. Now i want to include Insert2.jsp file into Insert.jsp.
So how can i do this please suggest me.

here is the code of Insert.jsp file

```
<form action="/Profile/sendData" method="POST">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<%@include file="Insert2.jsp" %>
```

Comment: spring and spring-mvc tags are not relevant for this question.

Comment: @Sitansu , yes it's possible !

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSTL `<c:import>` Tag in **Profile Project's `Insert.jsp`** like this :

```
<c:import url="http://localhost:8080/SecondProject/insert2.jsp"/>
```

**Note:** Don't forgot to add `jstl jar` in classpath and also below line:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

Comment: its Insert.jsp in Profile project

Comment: <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>  
<html>

<body>

<form action="/Profile/sendData" method="POST">
<p>
Name: <input type="text" name="name" />

<input type="submit" value="submit" />

</form>

<c:import url="Insert2.jsp"></c:import>
</body>
</html>

Comment: *you need to provide complete URL as mentioned above !*

Comment: HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Problem accessing the absolute URL "http://localhost:8080/SecondProject/Insert2.jsp". java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8080/SecondProject/Insert2.jsp

Comment: Use this : `<c:import url="http://localhost:8080/SecondProject/insert2.jsp"/>` and make sure your Second Project is deployed on Server and running
Secondly Is your insert2.jsp present outside directory any it's in any folder ?